# YU-NO: A Girl Who Chants Love at the Bound of this World change language to English

Tags: nintendo-switch, yu-no-a-girl-who-chants-love

Is it possible to change the language of "YU-NO: A Girl Who Chants Love at the Bound of this World" on Nintendo Switch (physical game) to English?

I've checked that there is an [english version for sale in nintendo store](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/yu-no-a-girl-who-chants-love-at-the-bound-of-this-world-switch/), but the one that I got was sold in Japan. BTW: My switch is set to use English as the default language, and I do have other Japanese games that work in English perfectly.

Do you think I can change the language of this game?

Comment: If it was purchased from a Japanese storefront, there may simply not be any English data on it. Posting as a comment as I have no way of checking if this is true; I don't own a Switch.

Comment: @qazmlpok It was purchased in a Japanese store. I've downloaded the updates before starting the game, but even with that no English text neither an option on config to change the language.

Comment: There are two distinct e-shop pages: [English](https://www.nintendo.com/store/products/yu-no-a-girl-who-chants-love-at-the-bound-of-this-world-switch/) and [Japanese](https://store-jp.nintendo.com/list/software/70010000014639.html). Each lists only one supported language. This suggests there is no language switch. If you own any switch games that do have language switch options, you could check their store pages for supported languages. I do not own a switch so I have no idea if this is typical or not.

Comment: @qazmlpok: First-party Nintendo games usually do have a language choice, but third-party games can do whatever they want (within reason).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YU-NO:_A_Girl_Who_Chants_Love_at_the_Bound_of_this_World#Remake):

> A high-definition video remake of the game was released in March 2017. It was developed by 5pb.

> An English localization was released by Spike Chunsoft on October 1, 2019 worldwide for Microsoft Windows, and in North America for Nintendo Switch and PlayStation 4.

You should check the release year or the developer of your copy. If you own the first one, I believe it's only in Japanese.

Comment: @qazmlpok of course it's the remake. I mean that there's a Japanese remake and an English localization for the remake.

Comment: I couldn't find how to check the release year on the box. If there are different versions for the same game that may not be possible.

Comment: When you start the game does the developer appears in a splashscreen?